# How to let other overlay activities to bypass my overlay activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am creating a lock screen app, i would like to let all other overlay activities to show on top of my lock screen activity.

Is there anyway to let other overlay activities like alarm activity, incoming call activity to bypass my overlay activity?

Comment: so basically you want call activity overlap lock screen while getting call ?

Comment: Not only call activity, There are other apps like third party alarms and power manager and many more. I would like to let them to show on top of my activity.